# Classify sentiment of 15K tweets, using NLTK for Python

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

Already trained a classifier with NLTK, it is a SVM classifier with an accuracy of about 80%. Now I saved this classifier with:

```
f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, f)
f.close()
```

and open it in another file with:

```
f = open('my_classifier.pickle')
classifier = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

which seems to work. Now I have one text file with 15K tweet documents, separated per line. How can I classify each line based on its sentiment (positive or negative in my case) and save these 15K classifications to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a lot of questions on here about "how do I..." but you aren't providing any real details on what you have tried.

Without any additional details, the answer is:

Read each line and classify it with your classifier. If you have a trained classifier, you just need to send each line into that classifier (assuming you do the appropriate pre-processing, etc).